# Create an AngularJS directive that does not immediately render?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple [AngularJS directive with a templateUrl](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). The directive is for a tooltip.

- Currently I append a hidden element. However the directive is used very frequently, so **hundreds of data <-> DOM bindings occur, and the page slows down to the point of becoming unusable**.
- I would like to only actually load the template, and append the elements when mouseovered.

[Reading the angular docs, there doesn't seem to be any way of making a directive delay rendering](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Am I missing something?

```
    // Tooltip directive
    return function(){
        return {
        templateUrl: 'someTemplate.html',
        replace: false, // Append our tooltip, rather than replace the element's contents.
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                $element.on({
                mouseenter: function () {
                    // Would like to render, and set up bindings, here (my question)
                    },
                mouseleave: function () {
                    // Destroy rendered element here (simple stuff, not my question)
                    }
                });
            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are going to need inject the `$compile` service to do something like this inside your callback:

```
templateMarkup = '<p> {{ property }} </p>';
$compile(templateMarkup)(scope);
```

I haven't thought through the exact steps to fit this into your code but let me know if that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've considered $compile, and this will solve the second problem of how to render the popup on demand, but how to I prevent Angular from immediately rendering in the first place?

Comment: In short, don't declare a template for your directive. If you do, Angular is going to take control of when it is compiled away from you (and compile it up front). Alternatively, you could add the markup as a module value `angular.module('myApp', []).value('popupMarkup', '<p>{{property}}</p>');` and inject it in your linking function. Or you could just declare that markup as a String variable inside your directive if you don't want to get too fancy.